# Add free Azure subscription to existing account

Tags: azure

I had a MSDN Azure subscirption which has now expired. How to I add a free subscription to my existing account ? When I try to signup using using the Azure free subscription link using my existing account I says the account already had a free subscription and can add the free subscription. At the moment I don't have any active subscriptions and want to access the free subscription services in my existing account. Thanks.

Comment: So you want to use Azure for free, indefinitely?

Comment: See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/msgulfcommunity/2014/09/15/how-to-activate-azure-benefit-for-msdn-subscribers/ - MSDN members have a certain amount of monthly credits

Comment: @Amy Not Azure for free indefinitely (That would be nice though) I am looking to use the free services in Azure as listed here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/free/free-account-faq/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add the free account to an already existing subscription. If you have Azure pass with credits you can add it to your existing subscription from [`here`](https://www.microsoftazurepass.com/)

if you want to start from scratch with a free 200 credits for the month, you can start fresh [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/).